# Binary searching a string array not finding searched string C#

Tags: c#, arrays, binary-search

I'm trying to search an object array with text that has been typed into a text box.

I have converted the object array to a string array however, I'm still not having any luck with finding the correct index

I'm using the inbuilt binary search option within c# as that has been requested. I cannot change from this.

If anyone can help that would be great - If you need anything from me don't be afraid to drop me a comment.

Here's the customer array

```
Customer[] cust = new Customer[20];
```

Here's the sorting method for the customer class

```
private void customerSort()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < customerPTR - 1; x++)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(cust[x].GSname, cust[x + 1].GSname) > 0)
                    {
                        customerSwapRoutine(cust[x]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and the swap routine

```
private void customerSwapRoutine(Customer book, int x = 0)
        {
            string tempString = cust[x].GSname;
            cust[x].GSname = cust[x + 1].GSname;
            cust[x + 1].GSname = tempString;

            string tempString2 = cust[x].GScID;
            cust[x].GScID = cust[x + 1].GScID;
            cust[x + 1].GScID = tempString2;

            string tempString3 = cust[x].GSlocation;
            cust[x].GSlocation = cust[x + 1].GSlocation;
            cust[x + 1].GSlocation = tempString3;

            string tempString4 = cust[x].GSemail;
            cust[x].GSemail = cust[x + 1].GSemail;
            cust[x + 1].GSemail = tempString4;
        }
```

Here's the customer class

```
class Customer
    {
        private string name, location, email, cID;

        public string GScID
        {
            get { return cID; }
            set { cID = value; }
        }
        public string GSname
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        public string GSlocation
        {
            get { return location; }
            set { location = value; }
        }
        public string GSemail
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }
        public string displayCustomer()
        {
            return GScID + " " + GSname + " " + GSlocation + " " + GSemail;
        }
    }
```

Here's the search method

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] str = new string[cust.Length];

            for(int y = 0; y < cust.Length; y++)
            {
                if(cust[y] == null)
                {
                    Customer nc = new Customer();
                    cust[y] = nc;
                    cust[y].GScID = "";
                    cust[y].GSemail = "";
                    cust[y].GSlocation = "";
                    cust[y].GSname = "";
                }

                str[y] = cust[y].GScID;
            }

            string stringcID = tbCUSTOMERID.Text;

            int found = Array.BinarySearch(str, stringcID);

            if (found < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Customer doesn't exist");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Customer found!");
                tbCUSTOMERID.Text = cust[found].GScID;
                tbCUSTOMERNAME.Text = cust[found].GSname;
                tbCITY.Text = cust[found].GSlocation;
                tbEMAIL.Text = cust[found].GSemail;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the sorting is happening?  Because you aren't passing the `x` parameter, I have reason to believe this method will always look at the 0 and 1 elements of the array instead of moving through the array.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at this part of your code:

```
for(int y = 0; y < cust.Length; y++)
{
                if(cust[y] == null)
                {
                    Customer nc = new Customer();
                    cust[y] = nc;
                    cust[y].GScID = "";
                    cust[y].GSemail = "";
                    cust[y].GSlocation = "";
                    cust[y].GSname = "";
                }

                str[y] = cust[y].GScID;
}
string stringcID = tbCUSTOMERID.Text;
int found = Array.BinarySearch(str, stringcID);
```

You are inserting a lot of new Customer objects into your cust array just before doing a `BinarySearch`. This will break the existing sorting.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Searches the entire sorted List for an element using the specified comparer and returns the zero-based index of the element.

The whole array should be sorted already just before the `BinarySearch`. 
So, either you need to sort your array again after adding these new `Customer` objects.
Or you should add these new `Customer` objects to the correct index in the sorted strings, so it can keep its correct sorting.

There is another bug, the `customerSort` function sorts using `GSname` field. But `string[] str` array consists of `GScID` fields. You should sort and search the same things.

So, your code is buggy. If you make sure of sorting, then it should work.